# Difficulty with Logic parsing ICAL feed

Tags: perl, parsing, logic, icalendar

I have been working on a code that will parse event information from an Ical feed. It is a huge block of data that I want to divide by key term. I need it to be done in an orderly way. I tried indexing the key terms and then having the program print what is between those indexes. However for some reason it became in infinite loop that printed all the data. I don't know how to fix it. DO NOT RUN MY CODE IT KEEPS FREEZING MY COMPUTER. I was hoping someone could show me what my problem is.

DO NOT RUN THIS PROGRAM

```
use strict;
use warnings;


use LWP::Simple;
use HTML::TreeBuilder;
use HTML::FormatText;

my $URL= get("https://www.events.utoronto.ca/iCal.php?ical=1&campus=0&
+sponsor%5B%5D=&audience%5B%5D=&category%5B%5D=");

my $Format=HTML::FormatText->new;
my $TreeBuilder=HTML::TreeBuilder->new;
$TreeBuilder->parse($URL);
my $Parsed=$Format->format($TreeBuilder);
open(FILE, ">UOTSUMMER.txt");
print FILE "$Parsed";
close (FILE);

open (FILE, "UOTSUMMER.txt");
my @array=<FILE>;

my $string ="@array";
my $offset = 0;     # Where are we in the string?


my $numResults = 0;

while (1) {
    my $idxSummary = index($string, "SUMMARY", $offset);
    my $result = "";
    my $idxDescription = index ($string, "DESCRIPTION", $offset);
    my $result2= "";
    if ($idxSummary > -1) {
        $offset = $idxSummary + length("SUMMARY");
        my $idxDescription = index($string, "DESCRIPTION", $offset);
        if ($idxDescription == -1) {
            print "(Data malformed: missing DESCRIPTION line.)\n";
            last;
        }
        if ($idxDescription > -1) {
            $offset = $idxDescription+ length("DESCRIPTION");
            my $idxLocation= index($string, "LOCATION", $offset);
            if ($idxLocation == -1) {
                print "(Data malformed: missing LOCATION line.)\n";
                last;
            } 

            my $length = $idxDescription - $offset;
            my $length2= $idxLocation - $offset;
            $result = substr($string, $offset, $length);
            $result2= substr ($string, $offset, $length2);

            $offset = $idxDescription + length("DESCRIPTION");
            $result =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g ; # Strip leading and trailing white space, including newlines.
            $result2 =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g ; 

            $numResults++;
        } else { 
            print "(All done. $numResults result(s) found.)\n";
            last; 
        }

        open (FILE2, "UOT123.txt")
        print FILE2 "TITLE: <$result>\n DESCRIPTION: <$result2>\n";
```

Any guidance you may have will be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Crosspost on PerlMonks: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=988015  (It's polite to mention that so that people don't put effort into solving a question that might have been solved elsewhere, and so that the collaborative effort might be based on the total discussion rather than just a part of it.)

Comment: Please include the actual code you are using (this code is missing some `}`'s) and indent it consistently.

Comment: Have you Googled for "Perl ical"?  The first hit is an article on how to parse iCal, and the second and third are CPAN modules that seem to handle your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was so inspired by your warnings that I had to run it.  I even installed the required modules to do so.  Your computer is probably just getting bogged down by the endless loop, not really crashing.

Looking at your code, the problem is almost certainly your indexing.  As it stands now, your looping logic is kind of a mess.  Your best bet would be to rethink how you are doing this.  Rather than using all of this logic, try making the loop dependent on going through the file.  That way, it will be much harder to make an endless loop.  Also, regular expressions will make this job much simpler.  This probably doesn't do exactly what you want, but it is a start:

```
while ($string =~ m/SUMMARY(.+?)DESCRIPTION(.+?)(?=SUMMARY|$)/gcs)
{
    print "summary is: \n\n $1 \n\n description is: \n\n $2 \n\n";
}
```

Some other quick points:

- Writing to a file and then opening it and reading the content back out again at the beginning doesn't make much sense.  You already have exactly what you want in $Parsed.
- If you just want to print a variable by itself, don't put it in quotes. This adds a lot of overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the following will assist you with your parsing task:

```
use Modern::Perl;
use LWP::Simple qw/get/;
use HTML::Entities;

my $html = get 'https://www.events.utoronto.ca/iCal.php?ical=1&campus=0&+sponsor%5B%5D=&audience%5B%5D=&category%5B%5D=';

while ( $html =~ /(Summary:\s*[^\n]+)\s*(Description:\s*[^\n]+)/gi ) {
    say decode_entities($1) . "\n" . decode_entities($2);
}
```

Sample Output:

```
SUMMARY:Learning Disabilities Parent Support Group
DESCRIPTION: Dates: Thursdays: May 24, June 21, and July 19

SUMMARY:"Reading to Write"
DESCRIPTION: Leora Freedman, Coordinator, English Language Learning Program, Faculty of Arts  &  Science

SUMMARY:The Irish Home Rule Bill of 1912:  A Centennial Symposium
DESCRIPTION: One-day symposium presented by the Celtic Studies Program, St. Michael's College
```

If html entities are OK within the text, you can omit using `HTML::Entities` and the `decode_entities($1)` notation, else you may get results like the following:

```
DESCRIPTION: Leora Freedman, Coordinator, English Language Learning Program, Faculty of Arts  &amp;  Science
```

Hope this helps!